# Web service calls and generics, strange behaviour

Tags: java, web-services, exception, generics, soap

I have a web service interface that looks like this:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface MyWS<T> {    
    @WebMethod Person getRow(int id);

    @WebMethod T insertRow(T a);    
}
```

The really strange thing is that the `insertRow` method ONLY works if I also have a method that returns a Person. Note that I don´t have to use `getRow` to get `insertRow` to work.

In other words: When I, from the client program, ONLY call `insertRow` on the web service, then it works ONLY if I also have a `getRow` method that returns a Person. If I remove the `getRow` from the webservice and then run the client program again, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class com.myproject.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.myproject.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
```

Strange, huh!

What is going on?

Comment: Is `com.myproject.Person` in the published jar?

Comment: Yes it is. That is what is strange! It doesn´t work.